# I need the input submitted on a form to appear on the page after using HTML and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need a page I am creating to take the submitted info and then display it on the page when submit is pressed. The way I have it now it prints the name, email, years of experience, date, references and additional comments. Compensation and Region selected print as undefined...

Please help!!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
info = document.getElementById("personalInfo");
    info.innerHTML = "<strong>Peronal Info: </strong>" + "<br>" + "Name: " + 
                    document.feedback.fname.value +
                    " " +
                    document.feedback.lname.value +
                    "<br>" + "Email: " +
                    document.feedback.email.value;

    info = document.getElementById("experienceSubmit");

    var compensationValue,regionValue;
    //Get compensation value
    for(var i=0;i<document.feedback.comp.length;i++){
        if(document.feedback.comp[i].checked){
        compensationValue = document.feedback.comp[i].value;
    }
}
    //Get region value
    for(var i=0;i<document.feedback.region.length;i++){
        if(document.feedback.region[i].checked){
        regionValue = document.feedback.region[i].value;        
    }
}


info = document.getElementById("otherSubmit");
    info.innerHTML = "<strong>Other information: </strong>" + "<br>" + "# of References " + 
                    document.feedback.reference.value +
                    "<br>" + "Additional Comments: " +
                    document.feedback.comments.value; 
return false;
}
</script>
</head>
<body background="../Assignment 5/_images/abstract_color_background_picture_8016-wide.jpg" >
<form   name="feedback" method="post" onSubmit="return checkform()">
        <section  id="pinfo" class="inputArea">
        <fieldset>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Last Name: </td>
                    <td><input name="lname"
                               type="text"
                               autofocus
                               required
                               placeholder="lname"                               
                               size="25" />
                    </td>
                </tr>                   
                <tr>
                    <td>First Name: </td>
                    <td><input name="fname"
                               type="text"
                               size="25"
                               required
                               placeholder="fname" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Email: </td>
                    <td><input name="email"
                               type="email"
                               size="40"
                               required
                               placeholder="....@hotmail.com" />
                     </td>
                </tr>
                    <td>Gender: </td>
                    <td><select name="gender">
                            <option selected disabled style='display:none;'>
                            Gender</option>                         
                            <option value="Male">Male</option>
                            <option value="Female">Female</option>                      
                        </select>

                </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </fieldset>
</section>
<section id="experience">
            <fieldset>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    <label for="experience">Years of Experience: </label>
                    <input name="experience" type="number" />
                  </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label for="date">Date</label>
                        <input name="date" type="date" />
                    </td>
              <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label for="comp">Compensation: </label><br>
                        <input name="comp" type="radio" id="Salary" value="Salary Selected">Salary &nbsp;
                        <input name="comp" type="radio" id="SalaryWB" value="Salary with bonus Selected">Salary with Bonus &nbsp;
                        <input name="comp" type="radio" id="Commission" value="Commission Selected">Commission &nbsp;
                    </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="region">Region: </label><br>
                    <input name="region" type="checkbox" id="East" value="East Selected">East &nbsp;
                    <input name="region" type="checkbox" id="West" value="West Selected">West &nbsp;
                    <input name="region" type="checkbox" id="North" value="North Selected">North &nbsp;
                    <input name="region" type="checkbox" id="South" value="South Selected">South &nbsp;
                </td>
              </tr>
          </table>
          </fieldset>
</section>
<section id="other">
<fieldset>
          <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                <label for="reference">References<br>0&nbsp;&nbsp 1 &nbsp;&nbsp 2 &nbsp&nbsp 3 &nbsp&nbsp 4 &nbsp&nbsp 5<br></label>
            <input name="reference" id="reference"
                    type="range" 
                    value="0"
                    min="0"
                    max="5"
                    step="1" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="comments">Additional Comments: <br></label>
                    <textarea 
                    name="comments"
                    rows="5" 
                    cols="20" 
                    placeholder="Please include any other pertinent information here"></textarea>                   </td>
            </tr>          
          </table>          
</fieldset>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        <input type="reset" value="Clear" />
</section>
</form>
<section id="personalInfo"></section>
<section id="experienceSubmit"></section>
<section id="otherSubmit"></section>
</body>
```

Comment: I figured out additional comments wasnt working because I forgot a +

Comment: All the others which aren't working are because of the same reason.

Comment: I added in all the +'s.. now compensation and region print undefined.

Comment: Is there a special way to print radio buttons and checkboxes?

Comment: Are you using jquery?

Comment: I think I'm using Javascript, not sure.. sorry I'm new to this.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are using to get the value of the checkboxes and radio buttons is wrong. You can use this piece of code to get the checked value of the radio buttons or checkboxes.

**Radio Buttons**

```
var radios = document.getElementsByName('comp');

for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++) {
    if (radios[i].checked) {
        // do whatever you want with the checked radio
        alert(radios[i].value);

        // only one radio can be logically checked, don't check the rest
        break;
    }
}
```

**Checkboxes**

```
var checkedValues = []; 
var inputElements = document.getElementsByName('region');
for(var i=0; inputElements[i]; ++i){
      if(inputElements[i].checked){
           checkedValues.push(inputElements[i].value);   
      }
}
var str = checkedValues.ToString(); // all the selected regions in a string.
```

Comment: Thanks, how could I put this in my code to keep the formatting that I have now? Do i get value from the checkboxes and put it in the code like this? document.feedback.str.value

Comment: you can put both of these into functions and then replace `document.feedback.region.value` and `document.feedback.comp.value` with the function calls.

Comment: are function created the same way in javascript as they are in Java?

Comment: I cant get this to work, when I call the function, it flashes the info then displays nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through the collection and check whether it is checked or not.

This code if for your compensation:

```
for(var i=0;i<document.feedback.comp.length;i++){
    if(document.feedback.comp[i].checked){
        alert(document.feedback.comp[i].value)
    }
}
```

This code is for your region:

```
for(var i=0;i<document.feedback.region.length;i++){
    if(document.feedback.region[i].checked){
        alert(document.feedback.region[i].value)
    }
}
```

Here is it in your code[ Added on request of user ]:

```
info = document.getElementById("experienceSubmit");

var compensationValue,regionValue;
   //Get compensation value
   for(var i=0;i<document.feedback.comp.length;i++){
        if(document.feedback.comp[i].checked){
            compensationValue = document.feedback.comp[i].value;
        }
    }
   //Get region value
 for(var i=0;i<document.feedback.region.length;i++){
        if(document.feedback.region[i].checked){
            regionValue = document.feedback.region[i].value;
        }
    }

 info.innerHTML = "<strong>Experience and Salary: </strong>" + "<br>" + "Years of experience: " + 
                    document.feedback.experience.value +
                    "<br>" + "Date of availability: " +
                    document.feedback.date.value +
                    "<br>" + "Compensation Chosen: " +
                    compensationValue +
                    "<br>" + "Region Selected: " +
                    regionValue;
```

Comment: This works, but how do I assign what is checked to a value so I can print it in the "<br>" + "Compensation Chosen: " +
                    document.feedback.comp.value +
                    "<br>" + "Region Selected: " +
                    document.feedback.region.value;" Statements?

Comment: And I don't want it to have a popup if possible either.

Comment: This only outputs one checkbox, how do I make it to output all boxes selected.